How to get an italic letter with a dot as accent in the symbols list
I want to use the symbol for the volumetric flow V (with a point on top of it).
But I also want to define it as a symbol to be shown in my listofsymbols at the end of my document. I have troubles defining it, because the \newsym command won't let me use the \Dot command, or even the mathmode by using $$.
I also tried to use \textit{.{V}}, but there was an error message aswell.
Do you have any idea how to solve this, expect for "using Q as symbol for the volumetric flow".

How do you prepare the list of symbols? Please, make a short, but complete example.from \documentclass to \end{document}.
